# Regex for a matching regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check with JavaScript & Regex that a test only validates any kind of string between pipes `|`

So these will test true

```
`word|a phrase|word with number 1|word with symbol?`
`word|another word`
```

But any of these will say false

```
`|word`
`word|`
`word|another|`
`word`
```

I have tried this

```
const string = 'word|another word|'
// Trying to exclude pipe from beginning and end only
const expresion = /[^\|](.*?)(\|)(.*?)*[^$/|]/g
// But this test only gives false for the first pipe at the end not the second
console.log(expresion.test(string))
```

Comment: sounds like a `.split("|")` job to me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `[^\|](.*?)(\|)(.*?)*[^$/|]` matches at least a single `|` but the `.` can match any character, and can also match another `|`

Note that this part `[^$/|]` mean any char except `$` `/` `|`

---

You can start the match matching any character except a `|` or a newline.

Then repeat at least 1 or more times matching a `|` followed by again any character except a `|`

```
^[^|\r\n]+(?:\|[^|\r\n]+)+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[^|\r\n]+` Negated character class, match 1+ times any char except `|` or a newline
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\|[^|\r\n]+` Match `|` followed by 1+ times any char except a `|` or newline
- `)+` Close group and repeat 1+ times to match at least a single pipe
- `$` End of string

[REgex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iyLR1N/1)

```js
const pattern = /^[^|\r\n]+(?:\|[^|\r\n]+)+$/;
[
  "word|a phrase|word with number 1|word with symbol?",
  "word|another word",
  "|word",
  "word|",
  "word|another|",
  "word"
].forEach(s => console.log(`${pattern.test(s)} => ${s}`));
```

If there will be no newlines present, you can use:

```
^[^|]+(?:\|[^|]+)+$
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work, however it will never be a new line, it was just an example of different combinations, it will always be a single line string